# Output window is not working in visual studio code while using python

Tags: python

In  visual studio code,when I run the code it is showing output in terminal **window.output**, but  **window** is not working...

Comment: Why not just click the terminal tab and run `python your_filename.py` directly?

Comment: Add OS and  VS version, include contextual information if there is an errorlog or tracebacks available and post relevant information from it in your question. This can also be a screenshot with arrow to indicated what goes wrong. Python version and how its installed is also relevant. Finally, post also info about what you've tried sofar to fix it.